# Error in using isull on datetime column in ms sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, datetime, isnull

I am using MS SQL SERVER 2008.

I am trying to fetch date column from database.
This value can be null.
How can i handle isnull for datetime column in ms sql server 2008?
If value is null i want to diasplay as '-' or ' '.

Comment: While the sql server replies below are perfectly correct, I think you should do this kind of conversion in your application rather than your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) the `datetime` column to `varchar`, then you can use `ISNULL`.

```
SELECT ISNULL(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateTimeColumn, 120), 10), '-') AS DateAsString
FROM dbo.TableName
```

[CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This may help, please see.

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD

DECLARE @DT DATETIME 

SET @DT = '2014-05-26' --GETDATE()
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DT,105),CAST('-' AS VARCHAR(10)))

SET @DT = null
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DT,105),CAST('-' AS VARCHAR(10)))
```

[image]